# JSF, XHTML, Richfaces, and jQuery version woes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces, conflict

I'm working in a JSF 1.2 application that uses Richfaces 3.3.3. I'm stuck with jQuery 1.3.2 as a result. To compound this, the`$`variable appears to be unused as it does not work in a component javascript function or within a `<script>` tag. I don't think it's even set. Whenever jQuery is invoked, it's done as`jQuery(...)`. This works out fine most of the time, but now I find myself needing a later version of jQuery for a particular component, and I cannot seem to get it imported without breaking things.

The page in question extends a template that is shared by many pages. Everything that extends this template is nested in an`<a4j:form>`. I cannot make major changes to it. About the best I can do is put a`<ui:insert>`in the`<head>`of the main template. Then I can use a`<ui:define>`in other pages to slip the new jQuery version into the head. This almost works, but it breaks some Richfaces components, particularly some client-switched `<rich:tab>`elements on the page (they do nothing when clicked, no mouseover styling), and I get a boatload of javascript errors in the console. Other javascript/jQuery functions work just fine. `jQuery.noConflict()`doesn't help. I'm not sure if other components are using`$`behind the scenes, though.

This is a rough idea of what I'm doing:

```
<ui:define name="jQueryOverride"> //Inserted in the <head> of the main template
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $132 = jQuery;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.8.2.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jqry = $;
        jQuery = $ = $132;  
    </script>
</ui:define>
```

When I add some`console.log()`statements to check the jQuery version, everything checks out. 1.3.2 is set for both`$`and`jQuery`, while `jqry` is set to 1.8.2. The log statements show up prior to the errors in the console.

I'm not sure how to go about this as it seems the JSF implementation is a bit unconventional on these pages and the usual methods of using a second version of jQuery don't seem to work.

Comment: hey I guess it's not a good idea to manually set the Jquery global var like the code block above, that can mess up with the overall initialization process, why don't you upgrade to JSF2? And use h:head and h:outputScript tags for your own page specific JS code ? It's safer

Comment: If I could, I'd upgrade out of JSF entirely, but that's not my decision to make. This is what I have to work with. I realize that it's not ideal, but the method I've tried here is one I've seen suggested on SO and elsewhere.